# How to call script include from the client script service-now without GlideAjax

Tags: saas, servicenow

The common process we follow today to get the data on client script:

**OnChange client script:**

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }
    var user = g_form.getValue('u_user');
    //Call script include
    var ga = new GlideAjax('global.sampleUtils');   //Scriptinclude
    ga.addParam('sysparm_name', 'getUserDetails'); //Method
    ga.addParam('userId',user); //Parameters
    ga.getXMLAnswer(getResponse);
    function getResponse(response){
        console.log(response);
        var res = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(res);
        g_form.setValue('u_phone',res.mobile_phone);
        g_form.setValue('u_email',res.email);
    }
}
```

**Script include:**

```
var sampleUtils = Class.create();
sampleUtils.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
    getUserDetails: function(){ //Function
        var userId = this.getParameter('userId'); //Params
        obj = {};
        var grSysUser = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
        if (grSysUser.get(userId)) {
            obj.mobile_phone =  grSysUser.getValue('mobile_phone');
            obj.email =  grSysUser.getValue('email');
        }
        gs.addInfoMessage(obj+JSON.stringify(obj));
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    },
    type: 'sampleUtils'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO Link: https://youtu.be/nNUsfglmj_M

As an alternative to `glideAjax` you can `EfficientGlideRecord`

```
new EfficientGlideRecord('sys_user')
.addQuery('sys_id', newValue) //On Change client script, we will get sys_id of user in newValue variable
.addField('mobile_phone', true) //Get display value
.query(function (egrSysUser) {
    if(egrSysUser.next()) {
        g_form.setValue('phone', egrSysUser.getDisplayValue('mobile_phone'));
    }
});
```

**What is EfficientGlideRecord?**

EfficientGlideRecord is the best alternate way to use GlideAjax.
It is a client-side API class from which you can perform asynchronous client-side GlideRecord-style queries while maximizing performance.

**Benefits:**

1. Low code configuration with Huge performance improvement.
2. No need to worry about security loopholes, because it enforces ACLs.
3. No more concerns about creating new client callable script includes and maintaining
   the logic there.

**Dependencies:**

To use the `EfficientGlideRecord` we need to commit the attached update-set or find the latest version from the given link  https://github.com/thisnameissoclever/ServiceNow-EfficientGlideRecord/releases.
Add the package to Portal record -> JS Includes.

and that's it, and you are good at using the `EfficientGlideRecord` syntax.

To know more about EfficientGlideRecord, Refer the below link(s):
https://snprotips.com/efficientgliderecord